# Troubleshooting connecting with the eosjs library to eos testnet on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, eos

we’re using the eosjs library, and have setup to connect to the eos mainnet and it's worked. The issue is when connecting to my aws instance running a testnet, i am getting 'failed to fetch' error:

i've tried using these from my instance as http-endpoints:
http://52.91.212.204:8888
am i using these correctly to connect?

my aws security config is open to all traffic

(btw, i added this to config.ini:
access-control-allow-origin = *)

also relevant, am using nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::net_api_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --contracts-console